# Not Counting Total Number of Occurrences in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need help counting a certain word row by row and populate the total number of occurrences under each column. Right now, the code I have is counting the total of a certain word up to column GM and anything after that column, I get #N/A. I do not know if that should happen or not. Here is the code I have so far.

```
Option Compare Text

Sub Count_Named_Entities()
Dim Sum_of_ABS01 As Long
Dim Sum_of_ABS02 As Long
Dim Sum_of_Academ As Long
Dim Sum_of_Active As Long
Dim Sum_of_AffGain As Long
Dim Sum_of_Affil As Long
Dim Sum_of_AffLoss As Long
Dim Sum_of_AffOth As Long
Dim Sum_of_AffPt As Long
Dim Sum_of_AffTot As Long
Dim Sum_of_ANI As Long
Dim Sum_of_Anomie As Long
Dim Sum_of_Aquatic As Long
Dim Sum_of_ArenaLw As Long
Dim Sum_of_Arousal As Long
Dim Sum_of_Begin As Long
Dim Sum_of_BldgPt As Long
Dim Sum_of_BodyPt As Long
Dim Sum_of_CARD As Long
Dim Sum_of_Causal As Long
Dim Sum_of_COLL As Long
Dim Sum_of_COLOR As Long
Dim Sum_of_COM As Long
Dim Sum_of_ConForm As Long
Dim Sum_of_ComnObj As Long
Dim Sum_of_Compare As Long
Dim Sum_of_Complet As Long
Dim Sum_of_DAV As Long
Dim Sum_of_Decreas As Long
Dim Sum_of_DIM As Long
Dim Sum_of_DIST As Long
Dim Sum_of_Doctrin As Long
Dim Sum_of_Econ01 As Long
Dim Sum_of_Econ02 As Long
Dim Sum_of_EMOT As Long
Dim Sum_of_EndsLw As Long
Dim Sum_of_EnlEnds As Long
Dim Sum_of_EnlGain As Long
Dim Sum_of_EnlLoss As Long
Dim Sum_of_EnlOth As Long
Dim Sum_of_EnlPt As Long
Dim Sum_of_EnlTot As Long
Dim Sum_of_EVAL01 As Long
Dim Sum_of_Eval02 As Long
Dim Sum_of_Exch As Long
Dim Sum_of_Exert As Long
Dim Sum_of_Exprsv As Long
Dim Sum_of_Fail As Long
Dim Sum_of_Fall As Long
Dim Sum_of_Feel As Long
Dim Sum_of_Female As Long
Dim Sum_of_Fetch As Long
Dim Sum_of_Finish As Long
Dim Sum_of_Food As Long
Dim Sum_of_FormLw As Long
Dim Sum_of_FREQ As Long
Dim Sum_of_Goal As Long
Dim Sum_of_Hostile As Long
Dim Sum_of_HU As Long
Dim Sum_of_IAV As Long
Dim Sum_of_If As Long
Dim Sum_of_Increas As Long
Dim Sum_of_IndAdj As Long
Dim Sum_of_Intrj As Long
Dim Sum_of_IPadj As Long
Dim Sum_of_Is_In_General_Inquirer As Long
Dim Sum_of_Kin As Long
Dim Sum_of_Know As Long
Dim Sum_of_Land As Long
Dim Sum_of_Legal As Long
Dim Sum_of_MALE As Long
Dim Sum_of_Means As Long
Dim Sum_of_MeansLw As Long
Dim Sum_of_Milit As Long
Dim Sum_of_Name As Long
Dim Sum_of_Nation As Long
Dim Sum_of_NatObj As Long
Dim Sum_of_NatrPro As Long
Dim Sum_of_Need As Long
Dim Sum_of_NegAff As Long
Dim Sum_of_Negate As Long
Dim Sum_of_Negativ As Long
Dim Sum_of_Ngtv As Long
Dim Sum_of_No As Long
Dim Sum_of_Nonadlt As Long
Dim Sum_of_NotLw As Long
Dim Sum_of_NUMB As Long
Dim Sum_of_Object As Long
Dim Sum_of_ORD As Long
Dim Sum_of_Ought As Long
Dim Sum_of_Our As Long
Dim Sum_of_Ovrst As Long
Dim Sum_of_Pain As Long
Dim Sum_of_Passive As Long
Dim Sum_of_Perceiv As Long
Dim Sum_of_Persist As Long
Dim Sum_of_PLACE As Long
Dim Sum_of_Pleasur As Long
Dim Sum_of_Polit01 As Long
Dim Sum_of_Polit02 As Long
Dim Sum_of_POS As Long
Dim Sum_of_PosAff As Long
Dim Sum_of_Positiv As Long
Dim Sum_of_PowAren As Long
Dim Sum_of_PowAuPt As Long  
Dim Sum_of_PowAuth As Long
Dim Sum_of_PowCon As Long
Dim Sum_of_PowCoop As Long
Dim Sum_of_PowDoct As Long
Dim Sum_of_PowEnds As Long
Dim Sum_of_Power As Long
Dim Sum_of_PowGain As Long
Dim Sum_of_PowLoss As Long
Dim Sum_of_PowOth As Long
Dim Sum_of_PowPtas As Long
Dim Sum_of_PowTot As Long
Dim Sum_of_Pstv As Long
Dim Sum_of_PtLw As Long
Dim Sum_of_Quality As Long
Dim Sum_of_Quan As Long
Dim Sum_of_Race As Long
Dim Sum_of_RcEnds As Long
Dim Sum_of_RcEthic As Long
Dim Sum_of_RcGain As Long
Dim Sum_of_RcLoss As Long
Dim Sum_of_RcRelig As Long
Dim Sum_of_RcTot As Long
Dim Sum_of_Region As Long
Dim Sum_of_Rel As Long
Dim Sum_of_Relig As Long
Dim Sum_of_Rise As Long
Dim Sum_of_Ritual As Long
Dim Sum_of_Role As Long
Dim Sum_of_Route As Long
Dim Sum_of_RspGain As Long
Dim Sum_of_RspLoss As Long
Dim Sum_of_RspOth As Long
Dim Sum_of_RspTot As Long
Dim Sum_of_Say As Long
Dim Sum_of_Self As Long
Dim Sum_of_SklAsth As Long
Dim Sum_of_SklOth As Long
Dim Sum_of_SklPt As Long
Dim Sum_of_SklTot As Long
Dim Sum_of_Sky As Long
Dim Sum_of_Social As Long
Dim Sum_of_SocRel As Long
Dim Sum_of_Solve As Long
Dim Sum_of_Space As Long
Dim Sum_of_Stay As Long
Dim Sum_of_Strong As Long
Dim Sum_of_Submit As Long
Dim Sum_of_SureLw As Long
Dim Sum_of_SV As Long
Dim Sum_of_Think As Long
Dim Sum_of_TIME01 As Long
Dim Sum_of_Time02 As Long
Dim Sum_of_TimeSpc As Long
Dim Sum_of_Tool As Long
Dim Sum_of_TranLw As Long
Dim Sum_of_Travel As Long
Dim Sum_of_TrnGain As Long
Dim Sum_of_TrnLoss As Long
Dim Sum_of_Try As Long
Dim Sum_of_Undrst As Long
Dim Sum_of_Vary As Long
Dim Sum_of_Vehicle As Long
Dim Sum_of_Vice As Long
Dim Sum_of_Virtue As Long
Dim Sum_of_Weak As Long
Dim Sum_of_WlbGain As Long
Dim Sum_of_WlbLoss As Long
Dim Sum_of_WlbPhys As Long
Dim Sum_of_WlbPsyc As Long
Dim Sum_of_WlbPt As Long
Dim Sum_of_WlbTot As Long
Dim Sum_of_WltOth As Long
Dim Sum_of_WltPt As Long
Dim Sum_of_WltTot As Long
Dim Sum_of_WltTran As Long
Dim Sum_of_Work As Long
Dim Sum_of_Yes As Long
Dim Sum_of_You As Long
Dim Sum_of_Bear As Long
Dim Sum_of_Ice As Long

Dim ActiveDocument As Object
Dim row As Integer
Dim txt As String

row = 3

Set ActiveDocument = CreateObject("Word.Document")

Do While Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(row, 1) <> ""

    txt = Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(row, 2).Value
    ActiveDocument.Content = txt

    Sum_of_ABS01 = CountChar(txt, "ABS")
    Sum_of_ABS02 = CountChar(txt, "ABS@")
    Sum_of_Academ = CountChar(txt, "Academ")
    Sum_of_Active = CountChar(txt, "Active")
    Sum_of_AffPt = CountChar(txt, "AffPt")
    Sum_of_AffTot = CountChar(txt, "AffTot")
    Sum_of_ANI = CountChar(txt, "ANI")
    Sum_of_Anomie = CountChar(txt, "Anomie")
    Sum_of_Aquatic = CountChar(txt, "Aquatic")
    Sum_of_ArenaLw = CountChar(txt, "ArenaLw")
    Sum_of_Arousal = CountChar(txt, "Arousal")
    Sum_of_Begin = CountChar(txt, "BeginS")
    Sum_of_BldgPt = CountChar(txt, "BldgP")
    Sum_of_BodyPt = CountChar(txt, "BodyPt")
    Sum_of_CARD = CountChar(txt, "CARD")
    Sum_of_Causal = CountChar(txt, "Causal")
    Sum_of_COLL = CountChar(txt, "COLL")
    Sum_of_COLOR = CountChar(txt, "COLOR")
    Sum_of_COM = CountChar(txt, "COM")
    Sum_of_ConForm = CountChar(txt, "ConForm")
    Sum_of_ComnObj = CountChar(txt, "ComnObj")
    Sum_of_Compare = CountChar(txt, "Compare")
    Sum_of_Complet = CountChar(txt, "DAV")
    Sum_of_DAV = CountChar(txt, "Complet")
    Sum_of_Decreas = CountChar(txt, "Decreas")
    Sum_of_DIM = CountChar(txt, "DIM")
    Sum_of_DIST = CountChar(txt, "DIST")
    Sum_of_Doctrin = CountChar(txt, "Doctrin")
    Sum_of_Econ01 = CountChar(txt, "Econ")
    Sum_of_Econ02 = CountChar(txt, "Econ@")
    Sum_of_EMOT = CountChar(txt, "EMOT")
    Sum_of_EndsLw = CountChar(txt, "EndsLw")
    Sum_of_EnlEnds = CountChar(txt, "EnlEnds")
    Sum_of_EnlGain = CountChar(txt, "EnlGain")
    Sum_of_EnlLoss = CountChar(txt, "EnlLoss")
    Sum_of_EnlOth = CountChar(txt, "EnlOth")
    Sum_of_EnlPt = CountChar(txt, "EnlPt")
    Sum_of_EnlTot = CountChar(txt, "EnlTot")
    Sum_of_EVAL01 = CountChar(txt, "EVAL")
    Sum_of_Eval02 = CountChar(txt, "Eval@")
    Sum_of_Exch = CountChar(txt, "Exch")
    Sum_of_Exert = CountChar(txt, "Exert")
    Sum_of_Exprsv = CountChar(txt, "Exprsv")
    Sum_of_Fail = CountChar(txt, "Failt")
    Sum_of_Fall = CountChar(txt, "Fall")
    Sum_of_Feel = CountChar(txt, "Feel")
    Sum_of_Female = CountChar(txt, "Female")
    Sum_of_Fetch = CountChar(txt, "Fetch")
    Sum_of_Finish = CountChar(txt, "Finish")
    Sum_of_Food = CountChar(txt, "Food")
    Sum_of_FormLw = CountChar(txt, "FormLw")
    Sum_of_FREQ = CountChar(txt, "FREQ")
    Sum_of_Goal = CountChar(txt, "Goal")
    Sum_of_Hostile = CountChar(txt, "Hostile")
    Sum_of_HU = CountChar(txt, "HU")
    Sum_of_IAV = CountChar(txt, "IAV")
    Sum_of_If = CountChar(txt, "If")
    Sum_of_Increas = CountChar(txt, "Increas")
    Sum_of_IndAdj = CountChar(txt, "IndAdj")
    Sum_of_Intrj = CountChar(txt, "Intrj")
    Sum_of_IPadj = CountChar(txt, "IPadj")
    Sum_of_Is_In_General_Inquirer = CountChar(txt, "Is In General Inquirer")
    Sum_of_Kin = CountChar(txt, "Kin")
    Sum_of_Know = CountChar(txt, "Know")
    Sum_of_Land = CountChar(txt, "Land")
    Sum_of_Legal = CountChar(txt, "Legal")
    Sum_of_MALE = CountChar(txt, "MALE")
    Sum_of_Means = CountChar(txt, "Means")
    Sum_of_MeansLw = CountChar(txt, "MeansLw")
    Sum_of_Milit = CountChar(txt, "Milit")
    Sum_of_Name = CountChar(txt, "Name")
    Sum_of_NatObj = CountChar(txt, "NatObj")
    Sum_of_NatrPro = CountChar(txt, "NatrPro")
    Sum_of_Need = CountChar(txt, "Need")
    Sum_of_NegAff = CountChar(txt, "NegAff")
    Sum_of_Negate = CountChar(txt, "Negate")
    Sum_of_Negativ = CountChar(txt, "Negativ")
    Sum_of_Ngtv = CountChar(txt, "Ngtv")
    Sum_of_No = CountChar(txt, "No")
    Sum_of_Nonadlt = CountChar(txt, "Nonadlt")
    Sum_of_NotLw = CountChar(txt, "NotLw")
    Sum_of_NUMB = CountChar(txt, "NUMB")
    Sum_of_Object = CountChar(txt, "Object")
    Sum_of_ORD = CountChar(txt, "ORD")
    Sum_of_Ought = CountChar(txt, "Ought")
    Sum_of_Our = CountChar(txt, "Our")
    Sum_of_Ovrst = CountChar(txt, "Ovrst")
    Sum_of_Pain = CountChar(txt, "Pain")
    Sum_of_Passive = CountChar(txt, "Passive")
    Sum_of_Perceiv = CountChar(txt, "Perceiv")
    Sum_of_Persist = CountChar(txt, "Persist")
    Sum_of_PLACE = CountChar(txt, "PLACE")
    Sum_of_Pleasur = CountChar(txt, "Pleasur")
    Sum_of_Polit01 = CountChar(txt, "Polit")
    Sum_of_Polit02 = CountChar(txt, "Polit@")
    Sum_of_POS = CountChar(txt, "POS")
    Sum_of_PosAff = CountChar(txt, "PosAff")
    Sum_of_Positiv = CountChar(txt, "Positiv")
    Sum_of_PowAren = CountChar(txt, "PowAren")
    Sum_of_PowAuPt = CountChar(txt, "PowAuPt")
    Sum_of_PowAuth = CountChar(txt, "PowAuth")
    Sum_of_PowCon = CountChar(txt, "PowCon")
    Sum_of_PowCoop = CountChar(txt, "PowCoop")
    Sum_of_PowDoct = CountChar(txt, "PowDoct")
    Sum_of_PowEnds = CountChar(txt, "PowEnds")
    Sum_of_Power = CountChar(txt, "Power")
    Sum_of_PowGain = CountChar(txt, "PowGain")
    Sum_of_PowLoss = CountChar(txt, "PowLoss")
    Sum_of_PowOth = CountChar(txt, "PowOth")
    Sum_of_PowPtas = CountChar(txt, "PowPtas")
    Sum_of_PowTot = CountChar(txt, "PowTot")
    Sum_of_Pstv = CountChar(txt, "Pstv")
    Sum_of_PtLw = CountChar(txt, "PtLw")
    Sum_of_Quality = CountChar(txt, "Quality")
    Sum_of_Quan = CountChar(txt, "Quan")
    Sum_of_Race = CountChar(txt, "Race")
    Sum_of_RcEnds = CountChar(txt, "RcEnds")
    Sum_of_RcEthic = CountChar(txt, "RcEthic")
    Sum_of_RcGain = CountChar(txt, "RcGain")
    Sum_of_RcLoss = CountChar(txt, "RcLoss")
    Sum_of_RcRelig = CountChar(txt, "RcRelig")
    Sum_of_RcTot = CountChar(txt, "RcTot")
    Sum_of_Region = CountChar(txt, "Region")
    Sum_of_Rel = CountChar(txt, "Rel")
    Sum_of_Relig = CountChar(txt, "Relig")
    Sum_of_Rise = CountChar(txt, "Rise")
    Sum_of_Ritual = CountChar(txt, "Ritual")
    Sum_of_Role = CountChar(txt, "Role")
    Sum_of_Route = CountChar(txt, "Route")
    Sum_of_RspGain = CountChar(txt, "RspGain")
    Sum_of_RspLoss = CountChar(txt, "RspLoss")
    Sum_of_RspOth = CountChar(txt, "RspOth")
    Sum_of_RspTot = CountChar(txt, "RspTot")
    Sum_of_Say = CountChar(txt, "Say")
    Sum_of_Self = CountChar(txt, "Self")
    Sum_of_SklAsth = CountChar(txt, "SklAsth")
    Sum_of_SklOth = CountChar(txt, "SklOth")
    Sum_of_SklPt = CountChar(txt, "SklPt")
    Sum_of_SklTot = CountChar(txt, "SklTot")
    Sum_of_Sky = CountChar(txt, "Sky")
    Sum_of_Social = CountChar(txt, "Social")
    Sum_of_SocRel = CountChar(txt, "SocRel")
    Sum_of_Solve = CountChar(txt, "Solve")
    Sum_of_Space = CountChar(txt, "Space")
    Sum_of_Stay = CountChar(txt, "Stay")
    Sum_of_Strong = CountChar(txt, "Strong")
    Sum_of_Submit = CountChar(txt, "Submit")
    Sum_of_SureLw = CountChar(txt, "SureLw")
    Sum_of_SV = CountChar(txt, "SV")
    Sum_of_Think = CountChar(txt, "Think")
    Sum_of_TIME01 = CountChar(txt, "TIME")
    Sum_of_Time02 = CountChar(txt, "Time@")
    Sum_of_TimeSpc = CountChar(txt, "TimeSpc")
    Sum_of_Tool = CountChar(txt, "Tool")
    Sum_of_TranLw = CountChar(txt, "TranLw")
    Sum_of_Travel = CountChar(txt, "Travel")
    Sum_of_TrnGain = CountChar(txt, "TrnGain")
    Sum_of_TrnLoss = CountChar(txt, "TrnLoss")
    Sum_of_Try = CountChar(txt, "Try")
    Sum_of_Undrst = CountChar(txt, "Undrst")
    Sum_of_Vary = CountChar(txt, "Vary")
    Sum_of_Vehicle = CountChar(txt, "Vehicle")
    Sum_of_Vice = CountChar(txt, "Vice")
    Sum_of_Virtue = CountChar(txt, "Virtue")
    Sum_of_Weak = CountChar(txt, "Weak")
    Sum_of_WlbGain = CountChar(txt, "WlbGain")
    Sum_of_WlbLoss = CountChar(txt, "WlbLoss")
    Sum_of_WlbPhys = CountChar(txt, "WlbPhys")
    Sum_of_WlbPsyc = CountChar(txt, "WlbPsyc")
    Sum_of_WlbPt = CountChar(txt, "WlbPt")
    Sum_of_WlbTot = CountChar(txt, "WlbTot")
    Sum_of_WltOth = CountChar(txt, "WltOth")
    Sum_of_WltPt = CountChar(txt, "WltPt")
    Sum_of_WltTot = CountChar(txt, "WltTot")
    Sum_of_WltTran = CountChar(txt, "WltTran")
    Sum_of_Work = CountChar(txt, "Work")
    Sum_of_Yes = CountChar(txt, "Yes")
    Sum_of_You = CountChar(txt, "You")
    Sum_of_Bear = CountChar(txt, "Bear")
    Sum_of_Ice = CountChar(txt, "ice")


    Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(row, 16).Resize(1, 185).Value = _
        Array(Sum_of_ABS01, Sum_of_ABS02, Sum_of_Academ, Sum_of_Active, Sum_of_AffPt, Sum_of_AffTot, Sum_of_ANI, Sum_of_Anomie, _
              Sum_of_Aquatic, Sum_of_ArenaLw, Sum_of_Arousal, Sum_of_Begin, Sum_of_BldgPt, Sum_of_BodyPt, Sum_of_CARD, Sum_of_Causal, _
              Sum_of_COLL, Sum_of_COLOR, Sum_of_COM, Sum_of_ConForm, Sum_of_ComnObj, Sum_of_Compare, Sum_of_Complet, Sum_of_DAV, _
              Sum_of_Decreas, Sum_of_DIM, Sum_of_DIST, Sum_of_Doctrin, Sum_of_Econ01, Sum_of_Econ02, Sum_of_EMOT, Sum_of_EndsLw, _
              Sum_of_EnlEnds, Sum_of_EnlGain, Sum_of_EnlLoss, Sum_of_EnlOth, Sum_of_EnlPt, Sum_of_EnlTot, Sum_of_EVAL01, Sum_of_Eval02, _
              Sum_of_Exch, Sum_of_Exert, Sum_of_Exprsv, Sum_of_Fail, Sum_of_Fall, Sum_of_Feel, Sum_of_Female, Sum_of_Fetch, Sum_of_Finish, _
              Sum_of_Food, Sum_of_FormLw, Sum_of_FREQ, Sum_of_Goal, Sum_of_Hostile, Sum_of_HU, Sum_of_IAV, Sum_of_If, Sum_of_Increas, _
              Sum_of_IndAdj, Sum_of_Intrj, Sum_of_IPadj, Sum_of_Is_In_General_Inquirer, Sum_of_Kin, Sum_of_Know, Sum_of_Land, _
              Sum_of_Legal, Sum_of_MALE, Sum_of_Means, Sum_of_MeansLw, Sum_of_Milit, Sum_of_Name, Sum_of_NatObj, Sum_of_NatrPro, _
              Sum_of_Need, Sum_of_NegAff, Sum_of_Negate, Sum_of_Negativ, Sum_of_Ngtv, Sum_of_No, Sum_of_Nonadlt, Sum_of_NotLw, Sum_of_NUMB, _
              Sum_of_Object, Sum_of_ORD, Sum_of_Ought, Sum_of_Our, Sum_of_Ovrst, Sum_of_Pain, Sum_of_Passive, Sum_of_Perceiv, _
              Sum_of_Persist, Sum_of_PLACE, Sum_of_Pleasur, Sum_of_Polit01, Sum_of_Polit02, Sum_of_POS, Sum_of_PosAff, Sum_of_Positiv, _
              Sum_of_PowAren, Sum_of_PowAuPt, Sum_of_PowAuth, Sum_of_PowCon, Sum_of_PowCoop, Sum_of_PowDoct, Sum_of_PowEnds, Sum_of_Power, _
              Sum_of_PowGain, Sum_of_PowLoss, Sum_of_PowOth, Sum_of_PowPtas, Sum_of_PowTot, Sum_of_Pstv, Sum_of_PtLw, Sum_of_Quality, _
              Sum_of_Quan, Sum_of_Race, Sum_of_RcEnds, Sum_of_RcEthic, Sum_of_RcGain, Sum_of_RcLoss, Sum_of_RcRelig, Sum_of_RcTot, _
              Sum_of_Region, Sum_of_Rel, Sum_of_Relig, Sum_of_Rise, Sum_of_Ritual, Sum_of_Role, Sum_of_Route, Sum_of_RspGain, _
              Sum_of_RspLoss, Sum_of_RspOth, Sum_of_RspTot, Sum_of_Say, Sum_of_Self, Sum_of_SklAsth, Sum_of_SklOth, Sum_of_SklPt, _
              Sum_of_SklTot, Sum_of_Sky, Sum_of_Social, Sum_of_SocRel, Sum_of_Solve, Sum_of_Space, Sum_of_Stay, Sum_of_Strong, _
              Sum_of_Submit, Sum_of_SureLw, Sum_of_SV, Sum_of_Think, Sum_of_TIME01, Sum_of_Time02, Sum_of_TimeSpc, Sum_of_Tool, Sum_of_TranLw, _
              Sum_of_Travel, Sum_of_TrnGain, Sum_of_TrnLoss, Sum_of_Try, Sum_of_Undrst, Sum_of_Vary, Sum_of_Vehicle, Sum_of_Vice, _
              Sum_of_Virtue, Sum_of_Weak, Sum_of_WlbGain, Sum_of_WlbLoss, Sum_of_WlbPhys, Sum_of_WlbPsyc, Sum_of_WlbPt, Sum_of_WlbTot, _
              Sum_of_WltOth, Sum_of_WltPt, Sum_of_WltTot, Sum_of_WltTran, Sum_of_Work, Sum_of_Yes, Sum_of_You, Sum_of_Bear, Sum_of_Ice)

    row = row + 1
Loop
End Sub

Function CountChar(txt As String, char As String) As Long
    CountChar = Len(txt) - Len(Replace(txt, char, ""))
End Function
```

Comment: do you need to do this in VBA? Doing it with plain excel formulas is probably much easier...

Comment: I need to do this in VBA because it is the requirement for my project.

Comment: Few questions: 1. Why do you create a `Word` object? 2. `CountChar` returns you the number of of your search term x number of occurrences. I guess you want the number of occurrences, instead? 3. Is the requirement really explicitly stating to fully do it in VBA?!? 4. You display the count in every row - but also increase it/do not reset the count each row. Is this what you want?

Comment: Last but not least: please accept the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010325/count-number-of-ampersands-and-exclamations-in-excel-text-row-by-row/15010782#comment21148610_15010782 - this will greatly increase motivation to help you! :-)

Comment: 1. I guess I do not need a word object. 2. Yes, let say I am searching for the word bear and bear appears 4 times in the text. At the column next to the text, I want the number 4 to appear and continue on so forth. 3. We were given the choices to use VBA or any open source software. 4. After it finishes finding all the queries for the first row, it will go to the next row, starting fresh and repeat the same queries for that row and continues.

Example:
Text ID: 1 Text: Polar bear walks on ice. Category: A Sum_of_Bear: 1 Sum_of_Ice: 1

Comment: Damn it, but i upvote this just for the effort spent to produce that enormous list of dims)))

Comment: @JeannetteLiu: So, did the solution below work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub CountAll()
    Dim varWords As Variant
    Dim txt As String
    Dim row As Long
    Dim i As 

    varWords = Array( _
        "ABS01", "ABS02", "Academ", "Active", "AffGain", "Affil", "AffLoss", "AffOth", _
        "AffPt", "AffTot", "ANI", "Anomie", "Aquatic", "ArenaLw", "Arousal", "Begin", _
        "BldgPt", "BodyPt", "CARD", "Causal", "COLL", "COLOR", "COM", "ConForm", "ComnObj", _
        "Compare", "Complet", "DAV", "Decreas", "DIM", "DIST", "Doctrin", "Econ01", _
        "Econ02", "EMOT", "EndsLw", "EnlEnds", "EnlGain", "EnlLoss", "EnlOth", "EnlPt", _
        "EnlTot", "EVAL01", "Eval02", "Exch", "Exert", "Exprsv", "Fail", "Fall", "Feel", _
        "Female", "Fetch", "Finish", "Food", "FormLw", "FREQ", "Goal", "Hostile", "HU", _
        "IAV", "If", "Increas", "IndAdj", "Intrj", "IPadj", "Is_In_General_Inquirer", _
        "Kin", "Know", "Land", "Legal", "MALE", "Means", "MeansLw", "Milit", "Name", _
        "Nation", "NatObj", "NatrPro", "Need", "NegAff", "Negate", "Negativ", "Ngtv", _
        "No", "Nonadlt", "NotLw", "NUMB", "Object", "ORD", "Ought", "Our", "Ovrst", _
        "Pain", "Passive", "Perceiv", "Persist", "PLACE", "Pleasur", "Polit01", _
        "Polit02", "POS", "PosAff", "Positiv", "PowAren", "PowAuPt", "PowAuth", _
        "PowCon", "PowCoop", "PowDoct", "PowEnds", "Power", "PowGain", "PowLoss", _
        "PowOth", "PowPtas", "PowTot", "Pstv", "PtLw", "Quality", "Quan", "Race", _
        "RcEnds", "RcEthic", "RcGain", "RcLoss", "RcRelig", "RcTot", "Region", _
        "Rel", "Relig", "Rise", "Ritual", "Role", "Route", "RspGain", "RspLoss", _
        "RspOth", "RspTot", "Say", "Self", "SklAsth", "SklOth", "SklPt", "SklTot", _
        "Sky", "Social", "SocRel", "Solve", "Space", "Stay", "Strong", "Submit", _
        "SureLw", "SV", "Think", "TIME01", "Time02", "TimeSpc", "Tool", "TranLw", _
        "Travel", "TrnGain", "TrnLoss", "Try", "Undrst", "Vary", "Vehicle", "Vice", _
        "Virtue", "Weak", "WlbGain", "WlbLoss", "WlbPhys", "WlbPsyc", "WlbPt", _
        "WlbTot", "WltOth", "WltPt", "WltTot", "WltTran", "Work", "Yes", "You", _
        "Bear", "Ice")

    While Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(row, 1) <> ""
        txt = Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(row, 2).Value
        For i = 0 To UBound(varWords)
            Worksheets("Sample_Output_2").Cells(row, 16 + i) = _
                CountOccurrences(CStr(varWords(i)), txt)
        Next i
    Wend
End Sub

Private Function CountOccurrences(strWord As String, strText As String)
    CountOccurrences = UBound(Split(UCase(strText), UCase(strWord)))
End Function
```

Comment: ...And this one is surely upvoted for dims reverse-engineering!)))) Nice one, Peter!

Comment: @Peter Albert: I had to tweak some of the little parts but overall code works. Thank you very much.

Comment: great! glad it worked! though two additional comments: 1. better to store the list of names in an Excel sheet than in code and simply read it in using `varWords = Range("A1:A185").Cells` 2. As said, this can be easily done purely with simple Excel formulas - VBA is overkill here - so normally you should push back the VBA requirement if possible

Comment: Just wondering is it possible to read a webpage from a hyperlink in excel and search the query from the web page and query the data back into excel without querying the webpage information back into excel first? Also it is possible from a file path?

Comment: @JeannetteLiu: I don't fully understand this question - but I'm sure this is a new question that should be posted as a question on SO instead of a comment! Also, search SO first, there have been multiple questions around this topic (though not sure exactly what you need was covered)

Comment: @JeannetteLiu: Just saw your question... :-)